# Getting alt by src on an htmlstring

Tags: jquery, html, parsing, selector

I want to get/change the alt attribute of an img with a known src.
The problem is, I can´t work directly in the DOM. My HTML is stored in a variable.

I have a HTML editor and my own picture editor. Changing the picture subline in the piceditor should update the affiliated img tag in the HTML editor.

The best I get is the first alt attribute of the content. I never could get the second.
I tried so many ways and now I´m stuck.

```
cnt=getEditorContent();
```

cnt looks like this:

```
<img alt="pic1" src="/data/18139/1.jpg" />
<img alt="pic2" src="/data/18139/2.jpg" />
<img alt="pic3" src="/data/18139/3.jpg" />
```

The whole function looks like this:

```
function refreshEditorAlt(src,newalt){
    var cnt;
    cnt = getEditorContent();

    alert($(cnt).html('img[src="'+src+'"]').attr('alt'));
    alert($(cnt).find('img[src="'+src+'"]').attr('alt'));
    setEditorContent(cnt);
}
```

It seems not to matter what I write in the html(...) part.
I also tried parseHTML but could only get the first alt as well.

Would be glad if someone can help me. I´m already 6 hours on this little problem.

Comment: The complete solution was a mix of two answers.

    function refreshEditorAlt(src,newalt){
     var cnt;
     cnt=getEditorContent();
        var newcnt = cnt.replace($(cnt).filter('img[src="'+src+'"]').attr('alt'), newalt);
     setEditorContent(newcnt);
    }

Thank You Forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try use filter(), instead find()

Comment: Maybe you are right. Your Answer is much more detailed but simply using filter solved the problem. Anyway all this does not work when cnt is more komplex. e.g. when the img is in a div

Answer (score 1):

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/Zjw8e/1/) how you can do it. You need to make relavent changes in your code.

```
function refreshEditorAlt(src,newalt){
    var cnt = '<img alt="pic1" src="/data/18139/1.jpg" /><img alt="pic2" src="/data/18139/2.jpg" /><img alt="pic3" src="/data/18139/3.jpg" />';
    var $imgToChange = $(cnt).filter(function(){ return this.src.indexOf(src) != -1 });
        $imgToChange.attr('alt', newalt);
    alert($imgToChange.attr('alt'));
}

refreshEditorAlt('/data/18139/1.jpg', 'new alt');
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe something like this would suit your needs:

```
  var cnttest = '<img alt="pic1" src="/data/18139/1.jpg" /><img alt="pic2" src="/data/18139/2.jpg" /><img alt="pic3" src="/data/18139/3.jpg" />';

 function refreshEditorAlt(src,newalt){
   var cnt;
   cnt = cnttest;


     var newcnt = cnt.replace($(cnt).html('img[src="'+src+'"]').attr('alt'), newalt);
     alert(newcnt);
     //setEditorContent(cnt);
}

 refreshEditorAlt('/data/18139/1.jpg', 'some new alt');
```

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/H26qK/)